# notifyDataSetChangedでListViewが更新される場合とされない場合がある

Tags: android

現在ListViewを使用してアプリを作っているのですが、adapterの更新で不可解な箇所がありましたので質問させていただきます。
ArrayAdapterを継承したMyArrayAdapterクラス内で

```
public void setData(MessageData mData) {
    this.messageData = mData;
    if (messageData.getMessageList().isEmpty()) {
        this.messageDetailList = messageData.getMessageList();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

としています。

データの更新があったら`setData`を呼び出してMyArrayAdapterを更新しているのですが、更新される場合とされない場合があります。

- MethodAから呼ぶと更新される: `getView`が呼ばれてListViewに反映される
- MethodBから呼ぶと更新されない: 更新されたデータだけ`getView`が呼ばれず、ListViewに反映されない(元々入っていた要素に関しては'getView'が呼ばれている)
- MethodA、MethodBはMainThreadから実行している(各メソッド内でThread確認済み)

ほとんど同じ処理であり、Listデータの数も更新されたものが渡されています。MyArrayAdapterが保持するListデータもMethodAの場合もMethodBの場合もsizeが更新されて数が増えているのですが、MethodBで実行すると新規で追加したデータに関してのみListViewに更新がかからない状態です。
MethodBで呼び出した場合は新規データの箇所のみMyArrayAdapterのgetViewが呼ばれず、
既存のデータに関してはgetViewが呼ばれます。
つまりMethodBの場合は表示が変更されません。

MethodBの実装
Hogeクラス内で

```
public void MethodB(JSONArray array){
    //JSONからListを取り出す
    ListmessageList=jsonUtil.getMessageDataList(array);
    if(messageList.size()!=0){
        userData.addMessageDataAll(messageList);
        userData=saveDataUtil.setUserData(userData);
        messageData=userData.getMessageData("ID");
        if(messageData!=null){
            //この時点では新規データが入っており更新されている
            messageData.getMessageList().size()="+messageData.getMessageList().size());
            adapter.setData(messageData);
            //ここでlist.getCount()したがサイズが増えていない。
            listView.setSelection(listView.getCount()-1);
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG,"messageData==null");
        }
    }
```

MethodAの実装

```
public void MethodA(JSONArray array){
            List detailList=jsonUtil.getMessageDetailList(array);
            Log.d(TAG,"送信したMessageDetail messageDetailList.size="+detailList.size());
            if(detailList.size()!=0){
                MessageDetail detail=detailList.get(0);
                messageData.addMessageList(detail);
                userData.setMessageData(messageData);
                userData=saveDataUtil.setUserData(userData);//userData保存
                messageData=userData.getMessageData("ID");
                if(messageData!=null){
                    adapter.setData(messageData);
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG,"userData.messageData==null");
                }
                listView.setSelection(listView.getCount()-1);
            }
```

MethodAとMethodBは共にVolleyのJSONArray取得メソッドから呼び出されています。
この場合どのような状況が考えられるのでしょうか？

Comment: 差し支えの無い範囲でMethodA, MethodBの実装についても記載した方が回答がしやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: [`Adapter`クラスには`notifyDataSetChanged()`メソッドはない](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)ので、`Adapter`を具体的にどう実装されているのかという点も気になります。`BaseAdapter`継承ならこの方法で更新されますが、`ArrayAdapter`継承の場合は一度`clear()`して`addAll()`なりする必要がありますし。

Comment: 質問は後から[edit]できますので、上でコメントされているような実装の詳細を共有すると、回答をもらいやすいと思います。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。
MethodAとMethodBの実装を追加いたしました。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: > messageData.getMessageList().size()="+messageData.getMessageList().size());

この行がコンパイルエラーになります。正しくはどう記述されたのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

推測になってしまうのですが、単に参照の問題だと思います。

`ArrayAdapter`はコンストラクタで受け取ったリスト（配列のオーバーロードコンストラクタでは、`Arrays.asList()`を利用してリストに変換する）を、`ListView`などに表示するアダプタです。

サブクラスを作る場合、「**`ArrayAdapter`が管理する`List<T>`は`private`であり、サブクラスから参照を変更できない**」という点に注意する必要があります。

`ArrayAdapter`は、[Class Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)にあるように一度保持したリストに対して、`add()`、`clear()`、`remove()`などのメソッドで操作するアダプタクラスになります。リストそのものの参照を外部から置き換えたい場合には、[`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)を継承した方が楽です。

表題の事象が起こり得るとすれば、以下のような原因かと思います。

- `MethodA()`の呼び出し側で更新しているリストは、`ArrayAdapter`のコンストラクタに渡したリストの参照なので、`ArrayAdapter`が内部で管理しているリスト＝`ListView`が更新される。
- `MethodB()`の呼び出し側ではリストを新規に生成して、`MyArrayAdapter`のメンバ変数を更新しているだけなので`ListView`は更新されない

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。

おっしゃる通り参照の問題だったようです。
add,clear,removeを使用して書き換えたところ思った動作になりました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

問題を再現できるコードが無いので、想像ですが：
原因として思いつくのは、以下です。

- ListViewに追加したつもりの要素が、実際には追加できていない
- 実はMethodAからの呼出でもgetViewが呼び出されている（が、確認方法がまずいなどの理由でgetViewが呼び出されていないと勘違いしている）
- ListViewに追加する処理が非同期で実行されており、notifyDataSetChanged()を呼び出したタイミングではまだ追加処理が完了していない（そのためgetView呼出されない）

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setData(MessageData mData) {
    this.messageData = mData;
    if (messageData.getMessageList().isEmpty()) {
        this.messageDetailList = messageData.getMessageList();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`adapter.messageData.getMessageList()`(代入しているので`mData.getMessageList()`)が空の場合のみ、その中身を adapter.messageDetailListに置き換えている為、`mData`の内容が、adapter.messageDataに追加されることは無いのでは、と思いました。

```
public void setData(MessageData mData) {
    this.messageData = mData;
    if (!messageData.getMessageList().isEmpty()) {
        this.messageDetailList.addAll(messageData.getMessageList());
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

が正しいのではないでしょうか。